# Scaffold-DbContext returns System.ArgumentNullException: Parameter name: proposedIdentifier in EFCore 2.0 when trying to pluralize

Tags: entity-framework-core, scaffolding

When I run command `Scaffold-DbContext "Server=localhost;Database=MyDatabase;Integrated Security=true" Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer`

I get an error:

```
System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: proposedIdentifier
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Utilities.Check.NotEmpty(String value, String parameterName)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Scaffolding.Internal.CSharpUtilities.Uniquifier(String proposedIdentifier, ICollection`1 existingIdentifiers)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Scaffolding.Internal.CSharpUtilities.GenerateCSharpIdentifier(String identifier, ICollection`1 existingIdentifiers, Func`2 singularizePluralizer, Func`3 uniquifier)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Scaffolding.Internal.CSharpUtilities.GenerateCSharpIdentifier(String identifier, ICollection`1 existingIdentifiers, Func`2 singularizePluralizer)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Scaffolding.Internal.CSharpNamer`1.GetName(T item)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Scaffolding.Internal.CSharpUniqueNamer`1.GetName(T item)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Scaffolding.Internal.RelationalScaffoldingModelFactory.GetEntityTypeName(DatabaseTable table)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Scaffolding.Internal.RelationalScaffoldingModelFactory.VisitTable(ModelBuilder modelBuilder, DatabaseTable table)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Scaffolding.Internal.RelationalScaffoldingModelFactory.VisitTables(ModelBuilder modelBuilder, ICollection`1 tables)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Scaffolding.Internal.RelationalScaffoldingModelFactory.VisitDatabaseModel(ModelBuilder modelBuilder, DatabaseModel databaseModel)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Scaffolding.Internal.RelationalScaffoldingModelFactory.CreateFromDatabaseModel(DatabaseModel databaseModel, Boolean useDatabaseNames)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Scaffolding.Internal.RelationalScaffoldingModelFactory.Create(String connectionString, IEnumerable`1 tables, IEnumerable`1 schemas, Boolean useDatabaseNames)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Scaffolding.Internal.ModelScaffolder.Generate(String connectionString, IEnumerable`1 tables, IEnumerable`1 schemas, String projectPath, String outputPath, String rootNamespace, String contextName, Boolean useDataAnnotations, Boolean overwriteFiles, Boolean useDatabaseNames)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.DatabaseOperations.ScaffoldContext(String provider, String connectionString, String outputDir, String dbContextClassName, IEnumerable`1 schemas, IEnumerable`1 tables, Boolean useDataAnnotations, Boolean overwriteFiles, Boolean useDatabaseNames)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.ScaffoldContextImpl(String provider, String connectionString, String outputDir, String dbContextClassName, IEnumerable`1 schemaFilters, IEnumerable`1 tableFilters, Boolean useDataAnnotations, Boolean overwriteFiles, Boolean useDatabaseNames)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.ScaffoldContext.<>c__DisplayClass0_1.<.ctor>b__0()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.OperationBase.<>c__DisplayClass3_0`1.<Execute>b__0()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.OperationBase.Execute(Action action)
Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: proposedIdentifier.
```

In my startup project I have:

```
public class CustomPluralizerDesignTimeServices : IDesignTimeServices
{
    public void ConfigureDesignTimeServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddSingleton<IPluralizer, HumanizerToIPluralizerAdapter>();
    }
}

public class HumanizerToIPluralizerAdapter : IPluralizer
{
    public string Pluralize(string name) => name.Pluralize();

    public string Singularize(string name) => name.Singularize();
}
```

when I remove this code, the scaffolding works.

Dependencies:

- DataAccess Project (.NET Standard 2.0)

  - Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer 2.0
  - Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools
  - Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design
- Startup Project (.NET CORE 2.0)

  - Microsoft.AspNetCore.All

Comment: `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer` you do not need to include this, unless you have both `EF 6` and `EF CORE`  nuget packages. If you have both installed, unless you absolutely need a reason for `EF 6` get rid of it

Comment: When I remove the parameter, I have to specify it as user input in the package manager console. See my edit for dependencies

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like a bug in your `IPluralizer` implementation. Ensure it's not returning null or an empty string for some values.